# Maven with dependency on "logback-classic" still gives "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory" exception

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project with the following dependencies in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However I'm still getting a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory" exception.

I also tried adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.20</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.20</version>
</dependency>
```

But they don't make any difference.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory with logback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401726/noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory-with-logback)

Comment: I tried adding "slf4j-api" and "slf4j-log4j12", but that doesn't change anything. Shouldn't these be added automatically actually?

Comment: I use to add `logback-core` also, but that shouldn't be the answer/cause of your problem

Comment: Check your dependency jars and see if they have that class or not...you can do this via `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` then cracking each dependency jar like `jar -tf target/dependency/my-jar-name.jar` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE**
This works fine for me. Are you sure isn't there any duplicate or versionational problem in your pom.xml?

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

**UPDATE2**

And also i excluded commons-logging in spring definition by the way.

Comment: That didn't help. I also updated my original question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hmm, so weird.I'm trying to get my thesis project to build outside of IntelliJ (there it does work). Could you try it out? https://github.com/circle-packing/best-fit

Comment: you should exclude commons-logging i guess.. but i excluded it from spring dependency and it seems like you don't use spring..

Comment: I added `<exclude org="commons-logging"/>` to my dependencies, but now I just get an error about "exclude" being an unrecognised tag.

Comment: add this : 
   <exclusions>
    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112522/discussion-between-the-oddler-and-cihan-seven).